# Load dataset with datasets library of huggingface

Tags: pytorch, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

I use load_dataset from huggingface library to load a jsonline dataset. Here's an example of the data point in the jsonline file:

```
{"tokens": ["На", "місці", "трагедії", "Безсмертний", "заявив", ",", "що", "«", "нелюдські", "вчинки", "можуть", "оцінюватися", "лише", ",", "як", "звірство", "»", ".", "Нагадаємо", ",", "11", "квітня", "на", "станції", "метро", "«", "Жовтнева", "»", "у", "Мінську", "стався", "вибух", ",", "в", "результаті", "якого", "загинули", "12", "людей", ",", "більше", "150", "отримали", "поранення", ".", "13", "квітня", "Лукашенко", "заявив", "про", "розкриття", "теракту", ".", "Інша", "справа", ",", "що", "немає", "ясності", ",", "хто", "за", "цим", "стоїть", ".", "Багато", "хто", "звертає", "увагу", "на", "те", ",", "що", "вибух", "скоєно", "неподалік", "адміністрації", "президента", ".", "Сам", "Олександр", "Лукашенко", "учора", "увечері", "провів", "термінову", "нараду", "і", "наказав", "знайти", "тих", ",", "кому", "потрібно", "зруйнувати", "стабільність", "."], "source_start": 31, "source_end": 31, "target_start": 73, "target_end": 73, "topic_id": "255715", "source_id": "T10", "target_id": "T129", "doc_ids": [0, 1], "label": 1}
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Couldn't cast
tokens: list<item: string>
  child 0, item: string
source_start: int64
source_end: int64
target_start: int64
target_end: int64
label: int64
to
{'tokens': Sequence(feature=Value(dtype='string', id=0), length=-1, id=None), 'label': Value(dtype='int32', id=1), 'source_start': Value(dtype='int32', id=2), 'source_end': Value(dtype='int32', id=3), 'target_start': Value(dtype='int32', id=3), 'target_end': Value(dtype='int32', id=4), 'topic_id': Value(dtype='string', id=5), 'doc_id': Sequence(feature=Value(dtype='int32', id=6), length=-1, id=None), 'source_id': Value(dtype='string', id=7), 'target_id': Value(dtype='string', id=8)}
because column names don't match
```

Here's the code to load the data:

```
custom_features = Features(
    {
        "tokens": Sequence(Value("string", id=0)),
        "label": Value("int32", id=1),
        "source_start": Value("int32", id=2),
        "source_end": Value("int32", id=3),
        "target_start": Value("int32", id=3),
        "target_end": Value("int32", id=4),
        'topic_id': Value("string", id=5),
        'doc_id': Sequence(Value("int32", id=6)),
        'source_id': Value("string", id=7),
        'target_id': Value("string", id=8),
    }
)

raw_datasets = load_dataset('json', data_files={
    'train': args.train_file,
    'dev': args.dev_file,
    'test': args.test_file
},features=custom_features)
```

If I remove the fields "topic_id, doc_id, source_id, target_id", the dataset is loaded correctly. However, I prefer to keep them in the jsonfile and just ignore them in the processed version of the dataset. Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your issue by adding `'doc_ids': Sequence(Value("32", id=9))` to `custom_features`.